# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare composerRequireDrupal8()

Tags: 8, drush, composer

I recently nstalled Drush using `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master` and it got installed successfully.

I ran command `which drush` and the terminal gave me /home/ravi/.composer/vendor/bin/drush.

I am not able to execute any command from the project root. I get this error.

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare composerRequireDrupal8() (previously declared in /var/lib/composer/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:63) in /var/www/html/study/drupal/8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

But when I `/home/ravi/.composer/vendor/bin/drush status`, then Drush works perfectly well.

Is there any way to use Drush from the project root?

PS: I have tried updating Composer, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please do not install Drush using composer global require.

Quoted from http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install-alternative/.

If you have Drupal 8 installed conventionally best practice would be to install Drush 8 globally by downloading the latest drush.phar, see http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/.

If your Drupal 8 site is composer based then Drush 9 is probably already included. If not see http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/.

Comment: So you mean, we should put drush.phar at the root of the project and use the same for routine stuff?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but normally you place the phar file where it can be executed globally as described in the documentation.